# iOS center a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an class which adds a UIActivityIndicator to a specified view. I want to center the UIActivityIndicator in the given view.

I thought this work correctly since the UIActivityIndicator wasn't on screen very long. Now I see that when I rotate the screen when he is active, the UIActivityIndicator isn't centered anymore.

The way I did it was:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake((view.frame.size.width / 2 - self.activityIndicator.frame.size.width / 2),
                          (view.frame.size.height / 2 - self.activityIndicator.frame.size.height / 2),
                          self.activityIndicator.frame.size.width,
                          self.activityIndicator.frame.size.height
                         );
```

Which gives a better result then:

```
self.activityIndicator.center = view.center;
```

Is there some way I can add a constraint so it stays in the middle even when rotated. I know this can be done in IB, but in code I have no idea?

Comment: Set the view's `autoresizingMask` so all 4 margins are flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code, plus:

```
self.activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
```

Comment: Only change your answer to this:     self.activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin); Made a typo in activityIndicator and resizing is lowercase. Will get best answer in 8 min